# Creating bucket in S3 without amazon acc only AWS keys

Tags: amazon-s3

I have a `AWS_KEY_ID` and `AWS_SECRET_ACCESS_KEY` for amazon s3. I don't know the account. How can I create a bucket in s3 in browser without entering the Amazon account only using the `AWS` keys?

Comment: Were you able to create your S3 bucket?

Answer (score 0):

You have two options: use the AWS CLI or s3cmd, In each case you'll first have to create a credentials file that contains the KEY_ID and SECRET_ACCESS_KEY. Here is a blog post explaining that:

http://blogs.aws.amazon.com/security/post/Tx3D6U6WSFGOK2H/A-New-and-Standardized-Way-to-Manage-Credentials-in-the-AWS-SDKs

Then download your utility of choice (AWS CLI or s3cmd), install, and use the command line to create your bucket.

This is an example using the AWS CLI:

`aws s3 mb s3://your-bucket-name --region us-east-1`

Here are some instructions on the two options:

- Use the AWS CLI:
  http://docs.aws.amazon.com/cli/latest/userguide/using-s3-commands.html
- Use s3cmd: http://s3tools.org/usage